# NPM uninstall packages not working

Tags: node.js

can someone help me to identify what the issues is to my cli code when uninstalling the npm packages. When i run this cli code (in the picture below), the npm not unistalling the packages but instead added it to my node_modules. I hope someone in this community can solve my problem and bring any solutions that i can try to solve this weird problem to me.

[image: NPM Uninstall packages]

Comment: Use `--no-save` instead of `--save-dev`?

Answer (score 0):

NPM package is being removed. The one which are being shown as added are already remaining packages. **This is the way node shows output in terminal**.

To verify, check your pacakge.json, there won't be any package named webpack-config.