# Not able to uninstall outdated, probably unused NPM packages

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am trying to revive the React project of an ASP.net solution. I managed to clean up the `package.json`, but I am not able to remove two packages, which are neither used in the project nor defined in the `package.json`.

Two packages refuse deletion: The output of `npm uninstall react-hammerjs` still reads

```
npm WARN react-slick@0.14.11 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-slick@0.14.11 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN react-hammerjs@0.5.0 requires a peer of react@^0.14.3 || ^15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

**Is this behavior expected?**

The workaround to simply delete the corresponding subfolders within `node_modules` to remove `react-slick@0.14.11` or `react-hammerjs@0.5.0` is also not possible since no such directories exists. **How do I proceed now?**

**PS**: According to `npm show react version` I have version 16.9.0 of React if that matters.

Related questions:

- [NPM uninstall packages not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48107444/npm-uninstall-packages-not-working)
- [Not able to uninstall NVM packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389683/not-able-to-uninstall-nvm-packages)

Comment: Are you sure those two packages aren't required by one of your dependencies? What is the output of `npm ls react-slick` or `npm ls react-hammerjs`?

Answer (score 0):

In contrast to my previous assumption, the two packages are actually used by `antd` as a `npm ls <package-name>` revealed:

```
>npm ls react-hammerjs
ui@1.3.3.7 C:\myProjectUI
`-- antd@2.10.0
  `-- rc-tabs@7.3.4
    `-- react-hammerjs@0.5.0

>npm ls react-slick
ui@1.3.3.7 C:\myProjectUI
`-- antd@2.10.0
  `-- react-slick@0.14.11
```

The issue was resolved with by updating the parent packages `npm install --save antd@latest`.